# Javascript Html - Cannot read property 'remove' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following code:

```
 var entry = document.createElement('li');
 entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameChild));
 entry.setAttribute('id', idDoChild);
```

And then, I'm trying to do this:

```
 cell1.innerHTML = "<img src='assets/trash' width='13px' height='13px' onclick='this.remove(); removeElement(" + idDoChild +")'>";


function removeElement (id){
    document.getElementById(id).remove();
}
```

But I've got the error:

```
Cannot read property 'remove' of null
```

What's happening? :(

Comment: `document.getElementById(id)` in `removeElement` is returning null.

Comment: Where does `idDoChild` come from?

Comment: idDoChild is a variable.

Comment: are you inserting `entry` into the document? if not, `document.getElementById` wont find it

Comment: how can I do it, Aravindan?

Comment: As in, `entry` needs to be in the `body` somewhere. For instance `document.body.appendChild(entry)`. This would insert the element at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I'm creating a list and appending lines. The list exists in the body. I want to delete some elements of that list - 
 "x.appendChild(entry);"

Comment: Can you try manually doing `document.getElementById(idDoChild)` in the console after inserting `entry`, what happens? or share a bit more code?

Comment: @Bny4W, what is `cell1`

Comment: i've got:
     var x = document.getElementById('list');
     (..)
     x.appendChild(entry);

Comment: cell1 is a cell from a table

Comment: You need to change this line to `cell1.innerHTML = "<img src='assets/trash' width='13px' height='13px' onclick='this.remove(); removeElement(\"" + idDoChild +"\")'>";`

Comment: notice the escaped `\"` quotes before and after idDoChild

Comment: Is your code well written?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's happening here, since I can't see your whole code. But my best guess is that if `idDoChild` is `"someId"`, you need to be calling `removeElement("someId")`. Instead, you may be calling `removeElement(someId)`. Check `cell1.innerHTML` after you have set it. What does it say?

Comment: Aravindan Ve, can you tell me how to pass a second argument called "pos" truth here ->> removeElement(\"" + idDoChild +"\") without causing error?

Comment: Is this the intended effect: `removeElement("someId", "pos")`? If so, then you can just pass it like this: `removeElement(\"" + idDoChild + "\", \"pos\")`